# I am trying to understand the following javascript code

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
    var ppElement=function(str_elmt){
      this.tagName=(str_elmt==null)?"div":str_elmt;
    }
    ppElement.prototype={
      constructor:ppElement,
      ppCreate:function(){
        return document.createElement(this.tagName);
      },
      ppAppend:function(){
        var prntObj=arguments[0];
        for(var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
          prntObj.appendChild(arguments[i]);
        }
      }
    };
    /*=====================================*/
    var ppLabel=function(str_txt){
      this.text=str_txt;
    }
    ppLabel.prototype=Object.create(ppElement.prototype,{
      constructor:ppLabel,
      ppCreateLabel:{
        value:function(){
          var obj,txtObj;
          ppElement.call(this);
          obj=this.ppCreate();
          txtObj=document.createTextNode(this.text);
          this.ppAppend(obj,txtObj);
          return obj;
        }
      }
    });
    /*=====================================*/
    var tempObj=new ppLabel("Jeff");
    tempObj.ppCreateLabel();
    /*=====================================*/
```

This code was written by me. I was trying to inherit methods of ppElement from ppLabel using object.create. I was little bit confused about object.create. I couldn't understand what is happening in object.create. The above code works for me, but i would like to understand it.

**Few more questions :**

- Does this implementation works in all browsers?
- How to inherit from 2 base classes from single derived class? If possible someone tell me how to implement them in prototype-constructor pattern (which I found them on the internet, and I have written the above code in that pattern).
- Does this kind of writing the code affects performance? (I chose this pattern because it was said that JavaScript is prototypical language. so i decided to write my code on prototype-constructor pattern)
- Can we use `__proto__`? I found in internet that the use of `__proto__` is deprecated.

If I made anything wrong in my code, please feel free to say that, it will be really helpful for me.

Thank You!!

Comment: It is convention to start constructor names with a capital letter, it makes it easier to understand the code. Also, consider using function declarations rather than function expressions for constructors too. Consider using *Object.assign* to extend the default *constructor.prototype* rather than replacing it. Perhaps this is better on *codereview*?

Comment: I`m no expert on JavaScript yet so maybe this link will help you
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
It seems like basic JavaScript so this should work on all browsers.
Inheritance from 2 base classes is a big no-no from my point of view - it could lead only to trouble.
Don`t know about performance nor about ___proto___
In general the code looks good but ........ consider using **TypeScript**. It will make the code more readable for you and it transpiles to JavaScript so all browsers are supported. Much better!

Comment: I'll try starting names with capital letters for constructors. Thank you @RobG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The above code works for me, but i would like to understand it.

There are many, many questions here and articles on the web on prototype inheritance, e.g. [*MDN: Inheritance and the prototype chain*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

> Does this implementation works in all browsers?

All that support *Object.create*, which was introduced in EMCA-262 ed 5, so that would be most. Perhaps you don't care about those that don't (e.g. IE 8 and lower). It's pretty easy to implement a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

> How to inherit from 2 base classes from single derived class?

There are no classes in ECMAScript. There are constructors and prototypes (and a class syntax, but it doesn't create classes as such).

Anyway, I think you've done that. There are different ways of going about it, but the end result is pretty much what you've done. That is, stack the required *prototype* objects on top of the *constructor.prototype*'s `[[Prototype]]` so they're all on instances' prototype chains.

> If possible someone tell me how to implement them in prototype-constructor pattern (which I found them on the internet, and I have written the above code in that pattern).

I think you've done that.

> Does this kind of writing the code affects performance? (I chose this pattern because it was said that JavaScript is prototypical language. so i decided to write my code on prototype-constructor pattern)

Affect performance compared to what? Plain functions without constructors? Unlikely. It's more a matter of semantics and how you like to read and understand code.

> Can we use **proto**? I found in internet that the use of **proto** is deprecated.

You *can* but it's not recommended. It's been added to an appendix of ECMA-262. If you need to access an object's `[[Prototype]]` directly there is likely a better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to do. But of course there are exceptions.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer all my questions @RobG.  Almost you have answered all my queries. I am not clear about inheriting two base classes. For one derived class I can able to inherit from only one base class. If you are willing, please help to solve this by giving me an example by adding another class and inherit them to ppLabel. Thank you!!

Comment: See [*MND: Classes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), which can also be done with traditional constructor and prototype structures, but most seem to like the new Class syntax.